# dynamically created boostrap 4 cards are displaying as a column instead of normal layout(rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

here's the js:

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=3';

async function getDataFromCinemasAPI() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    let cardContentForFilling = '<div class="container"><div class="d-flex flex-row"><div class="d-flex flex-col-md-4"><div class="card mb-4 box-shadow"><div class="card-body"><p class="card-text"> </p></div></div></div></div></div>';

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('.album.py-5').append(cardContentForFilling);
        let cards = $('.card-text');
        cards.eq(i).html((data[i]["title"]));
    } 
}

getDataFromCinemasAPI();
```

here's the html:

```
<div class="album py-5">

</div>
```

already tried using flex column/rows but nothing, they stay as a column and not as a row

[here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fabryy__/wnybuhge/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the `.container` every single time. You have to have them above. Something like this might work:

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=3';

async function getDataFromCinemasAPI() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();

  let cardContentForFilling = '<div class="d-flex flex-col-md-4"><div class="card mb-4 box-shadow"><div class="card-body"><p class="card-text"> </p></div></div></div>';

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('.append-here').append(cardContentForFilling);
    let cards = $('.card-text');
    cards.eq(i).html((data[i]["title"]));
  }
}

getDataFromCinemasAPI();
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="album py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row append-here">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

please don't use d-flex class bootstrap is already set his `col-**-*` class with related to flex-box.

show snippet in full-width.

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=3';
async function getDataFromCinemasAPI() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();

  let cardContentForFilling = '<div class="col-md-4 mb-4"><div class="card box-shadow"><div class="card-body"><p class="card-text"></p></div></div></div>';

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('.append-here').append(cardContentForFilling);
    let cards = $('.card-text');
    cards.eq(i).html((data[i]["title"]));
  }
}
getDataFromCinemasAPI();
```

```css
.card {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Teste</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
  <div class="album py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row append-here">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```